# Отправляется форма без валидации

Tags: jquery, ajax

Валидация есть,пишет что не введено что-либо,либо неккоректный ввод и тд.но форма отправляется без ней,просмотрел кучу форумов,нашел думал ответ, из за того что нехватает submitHandler'a но не тут то было,перепробывал кучу вариантов,3 час сижу,не как не могу понять в чем проблема, если отключить плагин validate и использовать дефолтную валидацию , то все работает

````
        $(form).validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                family: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true
                },
                text: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: 'Введите свое имя',
                },
                family: {
                    required: 'Введите вашу фамилию',
                },
                email: {
                    required: 'Введите вашу электронную почту',
                    email: 'Неккоректный адрес эл.почты',
                },
                phone: {
                    required: 'Введите ваш номер телефона',
                },
                text: {
                    required: 'Введите ваше сообщение',
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                $(form).submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '../mailer/smart.php',
                        data: $(this).serialize()
                    .done(function () {
                        $(this).find('input').val('');
                        $('.overlay').css('display','block');
                        $('.modal').css('display','block');

                        $(form).trigger('reset');
                        })
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    }
    validateForm('.form');
});```

html ```
 <form action="#" class="contacts__form form" id="form">
    <div class="form__item">
        <input type="text" class="form__name"  placeholder="Имя" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form__item">
        <input type="text" class="form__family"   placeholder="Фамилия" name="family" />
    </div>
    <div class="form__item">
        <input type="e-mail" class="form__email"  placeholder="Email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form__item">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form__phone"  placeholder="Номер телефона" name="phone" />
    </div>
    <div class="form__item">
       <textarea name="text" autocomplete="off" class="form__textarea" placeholder="Сообщение" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form__item">
        <button type="submit" class="form__submit">Отправить</button>
    </div>
   </form>
````

Comment: рабочий пример https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в чем была проблема,достаточно было добавить это,чтобы функция прекращала свое действие, если форма не валидна.

```
let $form = $(this);
if(! $form.valid()) return false;



$('.form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let $form = $(this);
        if(! $form.valid()) return false;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../mailer/smart.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function () {
            $(this).find('input').val('');
            $('.overlay').css('display','block');
            $('.modal').css('display','block');

            $('form').trigger('reset');
        });
        return false;
    });
```